# saving build data only in slave node Jenkins

Tags: linux, jenkins, continuous-integration

I set up slave node in Jenkins. However when I am running job in slave node, I realized that build data, workspace and log information are still save in master node(Jenkins server). Is there a way to save this data in slave node instead of master node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The job workspace is not saved to the master, unless you mark the entire workspace as an artifact - or you're using the [Copy to Slave Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+To+Slave+Plugin).  Build data, console log, test results and any artifacts are indeed saved on the master.  That is the general design of Jenkins; it really can't be changed.  Part of the reasoning is that the master is expected to be always on, but the slaves may come and go.  If the data is stored on slave that's not on, it's effectively lost.

Comment: Is there a way to store console logs on the slave ? or on an other slave not running the job ?

Comment: Not automatically, @codeGeass.  You can use the CLI or the REST API to retrieve the build's log and store elsewhere - either as a post-build step (but won't be complete) or from another job or external process.